# EF Core 2 cross database migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0, cross-database

I am trying to create a cross database migration by using EF Core 2.0

When I am at the office I work by using a shared sql server database with the team. For this reason the code uses a configuration that reference the sql server provider

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, serverOptions => {
    serverOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrations", "dbo");
});
```

When a new migration is created this make the migration code use specific configuration of the sql server provider like

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Customers",
    schema: "dbo",
    columns: table => new
    {
        EntityID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 255, nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table => {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Customers", x => x.EntityID);
    });
```

Please note the `Annotation` method.

When out of office I am using a postgreSQL instance installed on my mac and I need to have a slightly different migration which makes use of the specific postgreSQL provider

```
.Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),
```

I know that I can manually modify the migration to specify both annotation as this does not have impact when running on a specifica database type.

However manually modify the migration is a tedious and error prone job that I would like to avoid.

Is there any way to make EF generate both Annotation methods automatically?

I have also tried to use the DbContext OnModelCreating method by specifying options on the ModelBuilder

```
modelBuilder
    .HasAnnotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn)
    .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

or

```
modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseSerialColumns();
modelBuilder.ForSqlServerUseIdentityColumns();
```

but the generated migration it is always related to the provider used at that specific moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get EF Core to do it for you. What you're doing is the best approach. A slightly less tedious approach is to keep two separate sets of migrations--one for each provider.

See [EF Core Migrations with Multiple Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've completely missed the linked page. Also, I think that the approach of creating a new type derived from DbContext can be a good give-and-take. It is funny that you answered this question and you collaborated to the linked post: this absolutely means that I've got the best possible answer :)

Comment: lol, *and* I wrote the code for EF Core Migrations. I don't know if it's the best possible answer, but I sure hope it's a good one. ;-)